# How to sum the same field twice, but with different sum criteria in pivot tables?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

What I am trying to do seems to be very easy, but I can´t figure out yet how to do it.

Supposing that I have the following dataset:

[image]

All I want is to see the sum of old sells and new sells, plus the percentage of difference.
It would be:

[image]

But it seems that I can´t insert this % column in the pivot table.

If I put the data like this, I wouldn't have the % column.

[image]

So I was wondering if I can use the VALUE field twice, but for the first one tell it to only sum the values that are of type "Old" and for the second one only values that are of type "New"?

[image]

I didn't find anything in field options about criteria so I don't know if it's possible.

Oh, and I tried with Calculated Fields, something like:

```
=IF(OldNew = "Old", Value , 0) <-- For Old Values Sum.
=IF(OldNew = "New", Value , 0) <-- For New Values Sum.
```

But it didn't work either.

Thank you!

Comment: You are probably going to run into problems using semicolons to separate the arguments in your `IF` functions in the calculated fields. You should use commas.

Comment: I think your "desired" result has the values for "old" and "new" swapped?

Comment: @nickfless, I am sorry about this. I use the portuguese version of excel and it uses semicolons instead of commas. I forgot to translate this when I was writing this question. Thanks.

Comment: Ken, yeah you're right. I edited it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try adding a Calculated Item named `%` with Formula:

```
=New/Old
```

and formatting to suit.

Comment: Hey, that wasn't me. However, it seems I can't insert a calculated item in this case. In my case, it didn't work. Tks.

Comment: You cannot add 'new' in formula as long as this is not a column in source data field. Read the response written by ken.

Comment: @pnuts : i'd like a screenhot with unmodified source data, since i'm very interested on how you do such thing.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, I was doing it wrong. This definitely worked! Thank you!! Just to know: Is there a way I can set the type field for this "new column" to percentage field? I'm not sure how it'll behave with new values, or maybe I just have to set the entire excel column to percentage field.

Comment: Ok, this fits perfectly to my needs. Ty again.

Comment: @pnuts: okay, I misunderstood "calculated item" vs "calculated field".

Answer (score 1):

In the source data I created two new columns:

[image: newdata2]
Column OldValue formula:

```
=IF($B2="Old",$C2,0)
```

Column NewValue formula:

```
=IF($B2="New",$C2,0)
```

I then created pivot table, summing OldValue, NewValue, and a calculated field I defined as being NewValue / OldValue

[image]

Result (after cleaning up column titles)

[image]

Comment: My data is dynamic, so I believe it would work if I add this old/new column in my data source. I thought there was another way to do this inside of pivot table, but if not... I think it's the only way! Thank you.

Comment: If the data is coming from a SQL query in Excel the result should be a true Excel table.  In which case the calculated fields will automatically adjust and fill as the data set changes.  You can also ensure that your pivot table references the table itself.

Answer (score 1):

Ken answer is right. (+ : just one pivotTable ; - : is original data coming from SQL or somehting like this, making it "impossible" to alter easily ?)

But you may also...

- use "Getpivotdata" to make a "beautiful" table that will READ the pivotTable and calculate on the third column. 
  (+ : you can make it just look as you want it... ; - : when a new "Name" appears, you have to add it quite manually)
- Add a new column NEAR the pivotTable, watching out for "getpivotData" being made automatically, that will do the percentage easily. (+ : easy to maintain ; - : not very easy to read, since out of the table)

[image: exemples]

Comment: It's very useful, but in my case my data is filled automatically with an external data source, so the size of pivot table data is really dynamic. I think it would work if I create some macro stuff to fill the other column/table. But I thought there was another way to do this inside of pivot table. Thank you!